# How to get a list of kinases that phosphorylated a particular protein?

Tags: proteins, database, phosphorylation

I am analysing the protein [SF2](https://www.phosphosite.org/proteinAction.action?id=4175&showAllSites=true) (also named as SRSF1). In the database, it is shown that this protein is often phosphorylated at the 189th tyrosine residue.

I want to know which proteins could have phosphorylated the protein at this site. Is there a way to figure this out using databases? What about getting a list of proteins that phosphorylated SF2 at any site?

Answer (score 1):

I use PhosphoSitePlus too. I use it in combination with [ELM](http://elm.eu.org/) as it finds linear motifs and generally gives a good generic candidate.

The literature if not. Checking all close homologues sometimes pays off.

Checking protein protein iteraction databases such as StringDB or IntAct may help too, but that gets very iffy —XL-MS (a smoking gun) is rare and does not pick up low concentration enzymes like kinases.

*(A note: this question ought to have been asked in [bioinformatics SO](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/))*